# Search and append with regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text:

```
3/1
```

I want to amend it to be:

```
3/1 port id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find this:  `(\d+\/\d+)`

This means "the group of: 1 or more digits followed by a forward slash followed by 1 or more digits"

Then replace with this: `\1 port id`

Which means "the first group found followed by the literal text: ' port id'"

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just do a search and replace for `3/1` replacing it with `3/1 port id`?

Comment: My example was incomplete, I have the following:

3/1
3/2
3/3

and so on. That is why I want to be able to add lines to the end.